# Silverlight Toolkit ; Pie Chart Avoiding Some Colors

Tags: c#, silverlight, telerik

We need to create a chart for service types.
The types can be added dynamically and I don't have a proper color definition for each of them.

So we are using the Telerik Silverlight RadChart and everything was fine until the client came with a trick requirement. We shouldn't show two colors in the grid: Red and Green.

There is some way to avoid all red and green palette of colors and still be able to render the chart with random colors?

Comment: I ran into the same type of scenario, I finally just made them specify some colors (because the "don't want" color list kept growing) and just loaded them to it via RadChart.PaletteBrushes, would love to know a more eloquent way.

Comment: I know how to do it for Toolkit charts. Though I never worked with Telerik so I can't help.

Comment: @vorrtex Can you please answer the question saying **It works just the Toolkit**? At least I can try to use the same concept.

Answer (score 0):

A solution for Toolkit charts is to generate colors in C# code and completely rewrite the pie data point template. 
By the way I have found an article explaining the same approach for Telerik charts:
[Binding the Color of Series Items](http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/radchartview-populating-with-data-binding-the-color-of-series-items.html)

So if you want to eliminate 2 colors, just set some other colors to the `ChartItemModel.Color` property. C# code will be something like this:

```
public class ChartItemModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public double Value { get; set; }

    public Brush Color { get; set; }
}

var chartItems = new [] 
{ 
    new ChartItem { Title = "Item1", Value = 25, Color = (Brush)Resources["BlueBrush"] }, 
    new ChartItem { Title = "Item2", Value = 75, Color = (Brush)Resources["YellowBrush"] }
    // other items, the Color property of which doesn't have a red or green brush
};
// binding
```

And `PieDataPoint` template is copied from the built-in one and changed by adding the binding to the brush (`Fill="{Binding Color}"`):

```
<charting:PieSeries.DataPointStyle>
    <Style TargetType="charting:PieDataPoint">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="charting:PieDataPoint">
                    <Grid x:Name="Root" Opacity="0">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.1" />
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MouseOverHighlight" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0.6" Duration="0" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.1" />
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unselected" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SelectionHighlight" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0.6" Duration="0" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="RevealStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.5" />
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Shown">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Root" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Hidden">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Root" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0" Duration="0" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Path x:Name="Slice" Data="{TemplateBinding Geometry}" Fill="{Binding Color}" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" StrokeMiterLimit="1">
                            <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding FormattedDependentValue}" />
                                    <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding FormattedRatio}" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                        </Path>
                        <Path x:Name="SelectionHighlight" Data="{TemplateBinding GeometrySelection}" Fill="Red" StrokeMiterLimit="1" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" />
                        <Path x:Name="MouseOverHighlight" Data="{TemplateBinding GeometryHighlight}" Fill="White" StrokeMiterLimit="1" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</charting:PieSeries.DataPointStyle>
```